# Ultra beginner. Issues with hiding UIBarButton

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uibarbuttonitem

I dived into learning apps development couple days ago and faced my first problem. Basically what I'm trying achieve is to hide and disable back button when there is no UIWebView history. Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)backButtonPressed:(id)sender {
[webView goBack];
 }

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://nearom.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];

}

- (void) backButton{
if(webView.canGoBack == YES)
{
    back.enabled = YES;
    back.width = 0;
    back.title = @"back";
}
else {
    back.enabled = NO;
    back.width = 0.01;
    back.title =  nil;
 }

 }

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)thisWebView{

[self backButton];

 }
```

But backButton method isn't working. Could anybody explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add more of your code. The only strange thing I have seen is that you use a parameter `width`. What do you want to do with that?

What I can not see from your code is if you have assigned the webviewDelegate to self so that `webViewDidFinishLoad` gets called.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a Navigation Controller, you should do the following:

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = TRUE;
```